# Displaying custom cursor in the full screen mode - Flex 3.0

Tags: apache-flex

I am having trouble displaying a custom cursor in the full screen mode of my flex application. How can I do this?

Comment: What did you try? What is the problem that you are facing with it? Add more details so that we can figure out what's going wrong. I was able to change the cursor to custom cursor in the full screen mode without any trouble.

Answer (score 0):

`CursorManager.removeCursor()` [method](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/managers/CursorManager.html#removeCursor()) removes a cursor from the cursor list.

> If the cursor being removed is the currently displayed cursor, the CursorManager displays the next cursor in the list, if one exists. If the list becomes empty, the CursorManager displays the default system cursor.

I can't find a way to add a removed cursor back to the cursor list other than calling the `setCursor` again. The following code works in normal as well as full screen mode. There's got to be a better way, because the `customID` is incremented in each call - but at least it works fine.

```
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="vertical" 
    xmlns:local="*" >
    <mx:Button label="Custom" click="onCustomClick();"/>
    <mx:Button label="Default" click="onDefaultClick();"/>
    <mx:Button label="Go Fullscreen" 
        click="stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN;"/>
    <mx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.managers.CursorManager;

            [Embed(source="cursor.png")]
            public var CursorPNG:Class;

            private var customID:int;

            private function onCustomClick():void
            {
                customID = CursorManager.setCursor(CursorPNG);
            }
            private function onDefaultClick():void
            {
                CursorManager.removeCursor(customID);
            }

        ]]>
    </mx:Script>
</mx:Application>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using the same method you are talking about. I am calling the method which changes the cursor on the RollOver event of mouse on a Canvas. Then I call the restore cursor method on RollOut event which removes the previously assigned cursor and shows the system's default one. It all works fine in normal mode. Custom cursor appears and disappears on roll over and out of the Canvas.
But when I switch the canvas to full screen mode, the custom cursor only appears only for a moment or so. And then it disappears. No cursor on the screen. If you move out of the Canvas, the system's default cursor is only visible then.

Comment: Instead of posting new answers, use the `add comment` button for comments.